# Why $x \le (1+\frac {\ln(x)} {\ln(2)})^{\pi(x)}$ imply $\pi(x)\ge \frac {\ln(x)} {2\ln\ln(x)}$ for $x \ge 8$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $\pi(x) = |\{ p \le x : p \in P\}|$ denote the prime counting function $\pi:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb N$ and $P$ the set of primes.

The equality $$x \le \left\lfloor \prod_{p_i\le x} 1+\frac {\ln(x)} {\ln(p_i)} \right\rfloor \le \left(1+\frac {\ln(x)} {\ln(2)}\right)^{\pi(x)}$$

is stated to be true.

It should follow immediately that for all $x \ge 8:$ $$\pi(x)\ge \frac {\ln(x)} {2\ln\ln(x)}$$

However, can someone explain why this last inequality follows from the above inequality ?

Comment: Idea: take $\ln$ in starting inequality.

Comment: Then I must rewrite $$\frac {ln(x)} {ln(1+\frac {ln(x)} {ln(2)})} = \frac {ln(x)} {2 ln ln(x)}$$ ? How can this be done ?

Comment: Thank you Julien. This was just what I needed in order to prove the inequality. Also thanks to you Martin.

Answer (score 3):

There is no thery number involved in the proof:

You have
$$\left( 1+\frac{\ln x}{\ln 2} \right)^{\pi(x)}\geq x$$
Then, since $\ln$ is increasing,
$$\begin{align}
\pi(x)\ln(1+\log_2 x)&\geq\ln x\\
\pi(x)&\geq\frac{\ln x}{\ln(1+\log_2 x)}
\end{align}$$
so you are done if you show that $\ln(1+\log_2 x)\leq2\ln\ln x$, that is, $1+\log_2 x\leq(\ln x)^2$.

Define $f(t)=\left(t-\frac1t\right)\ln 2$. Differentiating you see easily that $f$ is increasing and with a calculator you can check that $f(\ln 8)>1$. Thus, for $x\geq 8$ you have
$$\left(\ln x-\frac1{\ln x}\right)\ln 2=\left(\frac{(\ln x)^2-1}{\ln x}\right)\ln 2\geq 1$$
hence,
$$(\ln x)^2-1\geq \log_2 x$$

Comment: Why are you using $\log_2$ when only $\ln$ is used ?

Comment: $\log_2 x=(\ln x)/(\ln 2)$.

Comment: What does c.q.d. stand for?