# For any natural number $x\ge 20$, we have that $\pi(x)>\frac{\ln x}{2\ln\ln x}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

For any natural number $x\ge 20$, we have that $$\pi(x)>\frac{\ln x}{2\ln\ln x}$$

, where $\pi(x)=$ the number of the set $\{p\in{\mathbb N}:p~ is~ a~prime~with~p\le x\}$ for each fixed $x\in{\mathbb R}$, which is so called [prime-counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) .

**My attempt :**

Fixed positive integer $x\ge 20$ and let $p_{i}$ runs over all the primes less than or equal to $x$, that is, let $p_{i}\in\pi(x)$ for all $i$.

As $x\in{\mathbb N}$, then we have that $$x=p_{i_{1}}^{\alpha_{i_{1}}}p_{i_{2}}^{\alpha_{i_{2}}}\cdots p_{i_{r}}^{\alpha_{i_{r}}}=\prod_{k=1}^{r}p_{i_{k}}^{\alpha_{i_{k}}}$$, where each $p_{i_{k}}\in\pi(x)$ and each $\alpha_{i_{k}}\in{\mathbb N}.$

Since each $p_{i_{k}}^{\alpha_{i_{k}}}\le x$, one has for $x\ge 20$ that $$\alpha_{i_{k}}\le \frac{\ln x}{\ln p{_{i_{k}}}}\le 1+\frac{\ln x}{\ln p{_{i_{k}}}}\le 1+\frac{\ln x}{\ln 2}<\left(\ln x\right)^{2}$$ 
For the last inequality : note that 
\begin{align*}
\left(\ln x\right)^{2}-\frac{\ln x}{\ln 2}&=\ln x\left(\ln x-\frac{1}{\ln 2}\right)\\
&=\ln x\left(\frac{\ln 2\ln x-1}{\ln 2}\right) \\
&\ge\ln 20\left(\frac{\ln 2\ln 20-1}{\ln 2}\right)\\
&>1\\
\end{align*} 
, where I use calculator to compute this value $\displaystyle\ln 20\left(\frac{\ln 2\ln 20-1}{\ln 2}\right)$ and  the first inequality holds by $
\ln x$ is an increasing function.

Therefore, one has that $$x=\prod_{k=1}^{r}p_{i_{k}}^{\alpha_{i_{k}}}<\prod_{k=1}^{r}p_{i_{k}}^{\big(\ln x\big)^{2}}$$

Now, I get the stuck. I have no ideal how to proceed, or is there another way that can prove this theorem ?

Any comment or advice I will be grateful.

Comment: I'm not sure what they expect you to do, but there's a really easy way to get a lower bound of $\pi(x)\geq\lfloor\log_2 x\rfloor$. Indeed, by Bertrand's postulate, if the primes are $2=p_1,p_2,\dots$, then $p_{n+1}<2p_n$ for every $n$. Therefore $\pi(2^n)\geq n$ which implies that $\pi(x)\geq\lfloor\log_2 x\rfloor$ since $\pi$ is an increasing function

Comment: Have a look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728905/why-x-le-1-frac-lnx-ln2-pix-imply-pix-ge-frac-lnx?rq=1